# Flutter code runs but still returns null checker error

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Can anyone help please. The code runs alright. But in the `debug console` I see this

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>

When I click on the line it takes me to the beginning of the stream builder in the code.

Code:

```
return StreamBuilder(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection(userCollection)
                            .doc(passenger.get("something"))
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          final status = snapshot.data!["something"];

                          Color? color;
                          Icon? icons;
                          if (status == 'Not Verified') {
                            color = Colors.red;
                            icons = const Icon(
                              Icons.close,
                              size: 10,
                            );
                          }
                          if (status == 'Pending verification') {
                            color = Colors.yellow;
                            icons = const Icon(
                              Icons.hourglass_bottom,
                              size: 10,
                            );
                          }
                          if (status == 'Verified') {
                            color = Colors.green;
                            icons = const Icon(
                              Icons.done,
                              size: 10,
                            );
                          }
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return IconButton(
                              onPressed: onPressed, //onPressed,
                              icon: Column(
                                children: [
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 48,
                                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                      snapshot.data!["something"],
                                    ),
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Positioned(
                                          bottom: 5,
                                          right: 5,
                                          child: CircleAvatar(
                                              backgroundColor: color,
                                              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                              radius: 7,
                                              child: icons),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: screenWidth * 0.12,
                                    child: TextScroll(
                                      "${snapshot.data!["something"]}   ",
                                      velocity: const Velocity(
                                          pixelsPerSecond: Offset(30, 0)),
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 10),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          return const SizedBox();
                        },
                      );
```

And when I navigate to a different screen, the second screen gives error. I don't whether it's because of this error or not. But please take a look at why I am getting this error in the debug console althought that particular screen is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes wrong on

```
final status = snapshot.data!["something"];
```

By using the `!` you basically tell the compiler "`data` definitely isn't `null`". But that's simply not true and that's what's throwing the error. What you would like instead in this case is:

```
final status = snapshot.data?["something"];
```

So change the `!` to a `?`. Which means "if `data` is not `null` take "something"  from it, otherwise just put `null` in `status`";

---

Another option is to simply move all code above

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
```

into the `if` as well, so you are sure that data is there. (unless `null` is actually a valid result from the data)